# Unity: OnGUI streamlining

Tags: unity

So like most games, I have inventory screens, equip screens, shop screens, and all that. I've previously been making each "screen" controlled by its own script (which is normal I think), and I draw the screens using GUI. 
However, I'm worried about having multiple OnGUI functions in my game (one OnGUI for each "thing" I draw [eg Inventory or Shop]) since OnGUI really isn't that best for performance. How should I solve this problem?

I thought about making each screen its own scene in the game but I wasn't sure if that would help things much.

Comment: If you're able I would upgrade to 4.6+ and use the new UI and be gone with OnGUI forever.

Comment: I have 5.0 lol -- so I'm assuming that I'm not doing things right?

Comment: Yes with 4.6+ you no longer have to use OnGUI to draw the UI. Instead you go to GameObjects->UI->Canvas in the menu and create a base Canvas Object. You then populate it with children GameObjects that can be Images, Text, Scrollbars, Views, etc... that persist in real time. So say you want to make a window you would add a Panel object as a child of the Canvas, assign a texture to its Image Source and that's it. You then treat it like any other GameObject, writing custom scripts to control its behavior, and creating more children beneath it, say a Text object for a title.

Comment: Here's a tutorial series showing how to set up the new UI features.  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui

Comment: this is fantastic :)

Comment: @JeremiahLeslie, would you consider adding this advice in an answer, so that nachime can accept it rather than leaving the question open? Or, nachime, if you'd like to detail the steps you took to fix your problem, you can write that up and accept your own answer. That will make a good resource for the next user who comes looking for advice about replacing their OnGUI functions.